# ARIMA prediction model

Tags: r, prediction

I was browsing tradingeconomics and I came across their forecast models which immediately captivated my interest. They describe them as

> "projected using an autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) model calibrated using our analysts expectations. We model the past behaviour of Japanese Yen using vast amounts of historical data and we adjust the coefficients of the econometric model by taking into account our analysts assessments and future expectations."

[image]

So, my question is.. how can I create the band throughout the whole data set? From what I have seen thus far in youtube tutorials is that ARIMA is only forward looking it doesn't go through whole data set. It appears to be a smoothing model; however, I could very likely be wrong. Also, can this be done in R?

Comment: [This](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) should be a good place to get started. It should be doable in R with `auto.arima` and the `forecast` package. ARIMA is forward looking, but it is possible the graph shown is from a portion of the data that was left out for testing of the model. Then the black line would be a forecast, with a prediction interval shown in the blue band, and the data shown is the test portion of the data.

Comment: Interesting Idea Matt! I will look into it tonight, thank you.